# Magento2 : How to call shared package in another module composer.json Magento 2 Market place

Tags: magento2, module, marketplace, dependency

My module A depends on B.I uploaded A in the marketplace and B as a shared package. I getting following an error while uploading an A module while submitting in the market place

> Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original
>   content. Environment: PHP 5.6.37 Magento 2.1 CE composer require
>   vendor/module-A:1.0.0 2>&1  ./composer.json has been updated Loading
>   composer repositories with package information Updating dependencies
>   (including require-dev) Your requirements could not be resolved to an
>   installable set of packages.
>
> Problem 1
>       - Installation request for vendor/module-A 1.0.0 -> satisfiable by vendor/module-A[1.0.0].
>       - vendor/module-A 1.0.0 requires vendor/module-B ^1.0.0 -> no matching package found.
>
> Potential causes:
>    - A typo in the package name
>    - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting see for more details.
>    - It's a private package and you forgot to add a custom repository to find it
>
> Read  for further common problems.

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.

I called following method in Module A

```
 "vendor/module-B": ">=1.0.0",
```

Note:I already uploaded Shared package successfully

Guide me How to call shared package in A module composer.json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check your **composer.json** file for the package name used in the require section. The error states that the **package name** doesn't exist or the package name with the specified name doesn't exist.

```
"require": {
    "vendor/module-name": "^1.0.0"
  }
```

So recheck the package name "vendor/module-name" here. Please also check if the package name with a specified version exists already.